# Modeling random subsets of items using lmer

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

I have a survey where participants rate the price they are willing to pay for different products. I am interested in whether a personality variable (say, income) predicts their price ratings.

I have 100 products in total, but participants only rate a random subset of 20 products.

How do I best model this?

My initial inclination is to use

```
lmer(price ~ income +  (1 | subject) + (1 | product), df)
```

But I am not sure if there are arguments to model this differently.

What are the current best practices in terms of this design?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, it seems that you have a crossed-design. In particular, you would expect that the price ratings from the same subject would be correlated, and likewise price ratings for the same product would also be correlated. Hence, the model you have specified is a good start for this design.

You could use it to evaluate how similar are subjects and products in their ratings.

Just to note that the model you’re fitting assumes normal error terms. It was not clear what type of outcome price ratings is (e.g., continuous, ordinal does it have boundaries) and whether the assumption of normal error terms would be appropriate.